# Missing Converter when using Spring LdapTemplate with Grails Validateable annotation

Tags: spring, grails, spring-ldap

I'm using the Spring LDAP ([docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/)) library in a Grails application. I have a class annotated with the @Entry annotation, so it is mapped to an LDAP server. This all works quite beautifully.

However, when I add the Grails @Validateable annotation (to enable validating the LDAP class similarly to Grails domain classes) and attempt to retrieve data from LDAP (i.e. a findAll operation on the LdapUserRepo, or similar), I get the following exception:
    Message: Missing converter from class java.lang.String to interface org.springframework.validation.Errors, this is needed for field errors on Entry class com.ldap.portal.LdapUser

Basically, it seems like the AST transformation performed by the @Validateable annotation is producing extra fields (namely the errors field) on the LdapUser object. It appears that Spring LDAP, in processing the @Entry logic, assumes a default mapping for the fields property (probably interpreting it as a string field on the LDAP object). When it gets nothing from the LDAP server, it attempts to set the field of type ValidationErrors to a value of type String -- an empty string.

I did some looking in github and found [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/odm/core/impl/DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java#L388) that seems relevant and may support my theory.

My question is: is this behavior expected for annotations, and how can one prevent fields added by one annotation from being inappropriately processed by another annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present the best workaround I've come up with for my specific issue is to add an errors field to my LdapUser object and mark it as transient (so that LDAP ignores it):

```
@Transient
ValidationErrors errors
```